# What are the metadatas for lingering potions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So on my server we have the plugin MobArena, and what we want is for players on an upgrade wave to get a lingering potion of healing. Now, the item format is like this:

```
<item>:[metadata]:<amount> {<>=required,[]=optional}
```

So I would normally set potions up by doing (health as example) `373:8197:1` So I know that a lingering potion has an ID of 441, but what would be the metadata for a healing lingering potion? Because I can't seem to find the metadata values for lingering potions anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.9, potions do not use a metadata value to determine the type of potion. Instead, the type of default potion is stored as a `Potion` string tag within the `tag` compound of the item format:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:lingering_potion",Count:1b,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:healing"}}}
```

Or via `/give`, which starts NBT input within the `tag` compound:

```
/give @p minecraft:lingering_potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:healing"}
```

A list of default potion IDs can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Item_data).